# Spring Item Writer producing file with first line prefix with non-printable characters

Tags: java, spring

I recently discovered that file produced by flat file item writer is prefixed with non printable characters. I have attached screenshot below. 
Project uses Spring 4.1.7 RELEASE jar with Spring batch version 2.2.5 RELEASE on java 8 platform. Any idea to resolve this?

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vM3vm.jpg)

[Update 03/20] This issue is resolved. Output file extension chosen was .out and for some reason when this file was created on Windows platform it had non-printable characters in the beginning of the line. When extension was changed to .txt, output was as expected. On Linux, output file with .out extension has no issues. To conclude, it was OS platform specific issue, but if someone knows actual reason behind this then please shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code to look at, I'm guessing you are writing a line (probably a String) out that contains nothing but NULL values in Java...hence you get NULNULNULNUL... in the file.